# xarray: How to apply a scipy function to a large netcdf dataset

Tags: python, dask, h5py, python-xarray

I have a large netcdf file with several variables. I need to do discrete integration along a dimension to a variable say temperature of shape (80,100,300000) with dimensions (time, depth, nodes). So, I tried with dividing the large dataset into chunks with xarray and then tried to apply the function scipy.integrate.simps, but failed.

```
import xarray as xr
import scipy.integrate as sci
ds = xr.open_dataset('./temperature.nc',chunks={'time':5, 'nodes':1000})
temp = ds.temperature
```

Kindly, help me with applying the simps function along 2nd dimension of a chunked variable and then save chunks to a netcdf file instead of dumping the whole data into RAM. I would like to do something like this

```
temp.apply(sci.simps,{'dx':5}).to_netcdf('./temperature_integrated.nc')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for [xarray.apply_ufunc](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html)

Perhaps something like the following would work for you (untested):

```
import xarray as xr
xr.apply_ufunc(scipy.integrate, ds.temperature)
```